# Let xjc NOT use inheritance for XSD inheritance

Tags: jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have this XSD/WSDL:

```
<xs:complexType name="SupplierArticle">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Article">
            <xs:attribute name="supplierArticleId" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Article">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="articleId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ean" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="isbn" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

jxc will generate two classes `Article` & `SupplierArticle`. And `SupplierArticle` will inherit all from `Article`.

There are two things I want: I want to determine/fix the order of the attributes in the final XML produced. And when I cannot do that (which is what I found when I tried to add the propOrder to the `XmlType` annotation of the `SupplierArticle`) I want the `SupplierArticle` to no longer inherit from `Article` but fully implement all attributes of `Article` inside the `SupplierArticle`.

Is this possible? (Using some settings or some plugin) And if so: how?

(The other solution would be that all properties of the super would go first as is indicated on some location on the internet but that does not seem to happen either.)

(I'm using Java 17 and I already am using [jaxb-tools](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools))

Comment: Hello @gkephorus. I'm one of the maintainer of the jaxb-tools set. Could you be more precise about the `propOrder` not working ? I guess we could provide some plugin based on splitting inherintence (the reversed way inheritence plugin works itself). Please create an issue in jaxb-tools if this is something you need. We'd be happy to help